# Does IDA support remote debugging in their Freeware Version?

Tags: ida, debugging, remote

I am unable to find if it does. This PDF linked [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/freefiles/remotedbg.pdf) says that from version 4.8 IDA Pro supports remote debugging. But I can't seem to find this in the UI for the Freeware Version 5.0. Or is it that IDA Pro and IDA Freeware are different irrespective of version number.

Answer (score 5):

I'll start by saying that there's already IDA Free 7.0 which is much better than version 5.0. However, both the free edition of IDA 7.0 and IDA 5.0 are not supporting **remote** debugging of any kind.

Hex-Rays stated that, and other limitations, in their IDA 5.0 freeware page (which is now replaced with version 7.0). I'm quoting from a [backed-up page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160108085821/https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml):

> The freeware version of IDA v5.0 has the following limitations:
>
> no commercial use is allowed
>
> lacks all features introduced in IDA > v5.0:
> v5.1, v5.2, v5.3, v5.4, v5.5,v5.6, v5.7, v6.0, v6.1, v6.2, v6.3, v6.4, v6.5, v6.6 v6.7 v6.8
>
> lacks support for many processors, file formats, **debugging** etc...
>
> comes without technical support

*(emphasizes are mine)*

A similar description is available on the [IDA 7.0 Freeware page](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) as well:

> The freeware version of IDA v7.0 has the following limitations:
>
> no commercial use is allowed
>
> lacks all features introduced in IDA > v7.0
>
> lacks support for many processors, file formats, **debugging** etc...
>
> comes without technical support

---

**Edit:**

As both OP and @blabb mentioned -- apparently, IDA 5.0 **do** supports local-debugging but is not supports remote debugging.

As can be seen in this screenshot from IDA Free 5.0, the "Debug application setup" window doesn't contain the settings for remote debugging:

[image]

In contrary, the [screenshot](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/freefiles/remotedbg.pdf) from the PDF attached by OP is showing these settings:

[image]

Comment: I see. However, the freeware version does come with support for a local debugger. I am yet to find anything that says explicitly that it doesn't come with support for remote debugging. I am confused.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. Updated my answer according to what you and blabb mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know ida free supported  debugging of x86 in the 32 bit version

i think the free v7 does not even run in 32 bit machine

[image]

Comment: yes, i tried running both 86 and 32b of IDA7.x, the executable clashes with system architecture.

Answer (score 2):

The recent release of IDA 7.0 Free (March 2019) supports local debugging.
The description on the website hasn't been updated yet, but see the following tweet by one of the IDA authors:

> Yes, we released the new IDA Freeware at the beginning of March, and yes, it includes native debuggers for all platforms. (Ilfak Guilfanov)

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/ilfak/status/1106285550699450369)

[image: IDA 7 Free with local debugger]

Still, no support for remote debugging though.